# How do I find the wps pin on a brother dcp-L2540DW?

Tags: pin, wps

Got a new laptop but I can’t find the wps pin to connect to the laptop.  How do I find it on the printer?

Answer (score 1):

There is no WPS Pin, you need to add a password.

On the printer, press Menu.

Press the Up or Down arrow key to select Network, and then press OK.

Press the Up or Down arrow key to select Wi-Fi Direct, and then press OK.

Press the Up or Down arrow key to select Group Owner, and then press OK.

Press the Up or Down arrow key to select On, and then press OK.

Press the Up or Down arrow key to select Manual, and then press OK.

When Wi-Fi Direct On? appears, enable the Wi-Fi Direct network.

The machine will display the SSID name and password for two minutes.

Write down the network name (SSID) and password. You will need this information later.

http://support.brother.com/g/b/faqend.aspx?c=sg&lang=en&prod=dcpl2540dw_us_as&ftype3=2041&faqid=faq00003085_004#Brother Machine